# I think the number of possibile value(s) of variable $\omega$ is 1 however actually it takes 2 values of angular frequency

Tags: signal-analysis

Sampling is done by $~F_{s}=4[\text{Hz}]$ against$~x(t)=\cos(2\pi t)+1$ and the below function is given.

$$y[n]=\frac{1}{2} \left\{ x\left[n \right] +x\left[n -1\right]  \right\}     $$

And it is said that $y[n]$ can be represented as the below form.

$$y[n]=A\cos(\omega' n +\theta)+K$$

$$A,\omega',\theta,K~~\text{are constants}$$

$$ x\left[n \right] =x \left( n T_{s}  \right)  $$

$$ = x \left( \frac{n}{4}  \right)  $$

$$ = \cos\left(2 \pi \left( \frac{n}{4}  \right) \right) +1 $$

$$ = \cos\left(\frac{\pi n }{2} \right) +1 $$

$$ \omega_{\text{input}}:=\frac{\pi}{2}  $$

Below equations are general ones of amplitude characteristics and phase characteristics.

$$ y\left[n\right] =H \left( \exp\left(j \omega\right)  \right) \cdot \exp\left(j \omega n\right)  $$

$$ = A\left(\omega\right) \exp\left(j \theta\left(\omega\right) \right)  \cdot \exp\left( j \omega n\right)  $$

$$ = A\left(\omega\right) \exp\left(j \theta\left(\omega\right) + j \omega n\right)  $$

$$ = A\left(\omega\right) \exp\left(j \left( \theta\left(\omega n \right) +\omega n \right) \right)  $$

$$ = A\left(\omega\right) \left\{ \cos\left(\theta\left(\omega\right) +\omega n \right) +j\sin\left(\theta\left(\omega\right) +\omega n \right)            \right\}  $$

$$ = A\left(\omega\right) \cos\left(\theta\left(\omega\right) +\omega n\right)+j A\left(\omega\right) \sin\left(\theta\left(\omega\right) +\omega n\right)   $$

$$ \therefore  A \cos\left(\omega' n + \theta \right) +K=A\left(\omega\right) \cos\left(\theta\left(\omega\right) +\omega n\right)+j A\left(\omega\right) \sin\left(\theta\left(\omega\right) +\omega n\right) $$

$$ A\left(\omega\right) =\sin\left(\frac{\omega}{2} \right)   $$

$$ \theta\left(\omega\right) =\frac{\pi}{2} -\frac{\omega}{2}   $$

For me, it is quite wierd that the  RHS contains 2 variables of $ n,\omega $ however the LHS only contains one variable $ n $

And of course, the only value of $ \omega $ is $ ~ \frac{\pi}{2} ~ $  I thought.

So plugging the value of $ \omega $ into $ A\left(\omega\right)$ and $ ~ \theta\left(\omega\right)  ~ $  ,

$$ A\left(\omega\right) =\sin\left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \right)   $$

$$ = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)  $$

$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  $$

$$~$$

$$ \theta\left(\omega\right)   $$

$$ = \frac{\pi}{2} -\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}  $$

$$ = \frac{\pi}{2} -\frac{\pi}{4}  $$

$$ = \frac{\pi}{2} \left( 1-\frac{1}{2}  \right)  $$

$$ = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}  $$

$$ = \frac{\pi}{4}  $$

$$ \therefore  A \cos\left(\omega' n + \theta \right) +K=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos\left(\theta\left(\omega\right) +\omega n\right)+j \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin\left(\theta\left(\omega\right) +\omega n\right) $$

$$ \therefore  A \cos\left(\omega' n + \theta \right) +K=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}  +\omega n\right)+j \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}  +\omega n\right)$$

$$ \therefore  A \cos\left(\omega' n + \theta \right) +K=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}  +\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot  n\right)+j \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}  +\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot  n\right)$$

It is easiliy to get $~ A,\theta ,\omega' ~$ $~ \rightarrow  ~$ $~ A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 } } ~,~ \theta =\frac{\pi}{4} ~,~ \omega'=\frac{\pi}{2}  ~$

However the problem is the rightmost term of the RHS.

Since $~ K ~$ is a constant,$~ K \neq j \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}  +\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot  n\right)~ \leftarrow \text{no such value of n makes K=0} $

What the official descriptions states are below.

As $~ \omega=\frac{\pi}{2}  ~,~  A\left(\omega\right) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 } } ~,~ \theta\left(\omega\right) =\frac{\pi}{4} \leftarrow \text{same as I computed} ~$

As $~ \omega=0 ~,~ A\left(\omega\right) =A\left(0\right)  =0~$ hence $~ K=0 ~$

Why the $~ \omega ~$ can take zero ? I think $~ \omega ~$ can take $~ \frac{\pi}{2}  ~$ only.

What have I've been missing?

Comment: I see the first equation, and then how it can be represented, but can you add as the second line what it is exactly you are trying to determine? It is not clear to me what you are trying to do with your equations starting "Below equations are general ones of amplitude characteristics and phase characteristics." and would be clearer if you stated your objective of what result you are looking for first. Thanks!

Comment: $\omega = 0$ is a perfectly valid frequency. Your signal as TWO frequencies in it, one of them is being 0 Hz.

Comment: I think I should study more of signal processing to get the solution.